# How can I find the offending line of code in Web Developer 2010 Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I’m having problems debugging my program.  When I click on the submit button I get the Yahoo’s search engine message:  Page not found message that looks like this:

```
    The requested URL http://localhost:000000/MyController/ControllerAction/7?hsimp=yhse-001
```

cannot be found or is not available. Please check the spelling or try again later.

This does not leave me with any clue as to which line of code or the location of the problem.

In Chrome developer tool I find the line below

```
 Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) errorhandler?hsimp=yhse-001&hspart=CND&type=A75DB878ECBE148E7B6F_s_g_e&q=http://localhost:000000/Att…:2
```

Still confused as to how it relates to my problem.  Seems to be referencing screen resolution.  How can I find the offending line of code in Web Developer 2010 Express?

Comment: This sounds like a confusing mix of several observations.  The Chrome message is just talking about your CSS styling, which wouldn't cause an error (at worst it would make the page look wrong).  The first error message just indicates that the page can't be found.  What does that have to do with Yahoo?  Normally a page not found error suggests that the URL is wrong, or the server-side code isn't configured to return a response for that URL.  But one thing in your URL is *very* suspicious.  Port number `000000` probably won't work.  Where is that link coming from?

Comment: Sorry I replaced with 000..

Comment: You "replaced with 000" in your code?  That would be causing the problem then.  Or do you mean you replaced it in your Stack Overflow question only?  If that's the case, why?  It distracts from what might be causing the actual problem.  What *is* the link being rendered, and does that URL exist?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't caused a bug in your program code, so there is no "offending line".

It's a problem with your server configuration. But why is Yahoo Search coming up for a `localhost` resource?

That said, `localhost:000000` is not valid. Port numbers must be between `1` and `65535` and do not have leading zeros. Where is `000000` coming from?